# Reducing if else branches and cleaning code using chain of functions, does it make sense

Tags: java, if-statement, design-patterns, lambda, refactoring

I am working on legacy code that has lots of if/else. I can use conditional decomposition and/or guard statements etc. to clean it. Another approach which can be used is to create functions out of branches and execute these functions as chain and exit with first response. I am wondering if using function chain is an overkill? Any views?

My chain looks something like below. This is a simplified example.

```
public class RequestStateHandler {
    private final List<Function<RequestStateInfo, Optional<Response>>> handlers = new ArrayList<>();

    public RequestStateHandler() {
        handlers.add(requestStateInfo -> xStateValidator(requestStateInfo));
        handlers.add(requestStateInfo -> yStateValidator(requestStateInfo));
        handlers.add(requestStateInfo -> zStateValidator(requestStateInfo));
    }

    public Response getResponse(RequestStateInfo requestStateInfo) {
        try {
            for (final Function<RequestStateInfo, Optional<Response>> handler : handlers) {
                final Optional<Response> response = handler.apply(requestStateInfo);

                if (response.isPresent()) {
                    return response.get();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Some log", e);
        }

        return getDefaultResponse(requestStateInfo);
    }

    private Optional<Response> xStateValidator(RequestStateInfo requestStateInfo) {
        final A a = requestStateInfo.getA();
        if (a.isABC()) {
            return Optional.of(requestStateInfo.getX());
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }

    private Optional<Response> yStateValidator(RequestStateInfo requestStateInfo) {
        if (requestStateInfo.isXYZ()) {
            final Response response = requestStateInfo.getX();
            final A a = response.getA();
            if (a.isSomeOtherTest()) {
                return Optional.of(response);
            }
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }

    private Optional<Response> zStateValidator(RequestStateInfo requestStateInfo) {
        final Response response = requestStateInfo.getX();
        final A a = response.getA();
        if (a.isSomeAnotherTest()) {
            return Optional.of(response);
        }

        return Optional.of(getDefaultResponse(requestStateInfo));
    }

    private Response getDefaultResponse(RequestStateInfo requestStateInfo) {
        return new Response(A.create(requestStateInfo.getY()), null, null, null);
    }
}
```

I thought of creating a reusable executor so that we can have only business logic here. To me it looks much cleaner but it obviously add a dependency to execute the functions in order. Something like chain of responsibility, I would say. What are your thoughts?

A generic executor could be something like:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class ChainedExecutor<T, R> {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChainedExecutor.class);
    public final List<Function<T,Optional<R>>> handlers;
    private R defaultResponse;

    private ChainedExecutor() {
        this.handlers = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public R execute(T request) {
        return execute(request, Optional.empty(), Optional.empty());
    }

    public R execute(T request, Function<T, R> defaultSupplier) {
        return execute(request, Optional.of(defaultSupplier), Optional.empty());
    }

    public R execute(T request, Consumer<Exception> exceptionHandler) {
        return execute(request, Optional.empty() ,Optional.of(exceptionHandler));
    }

    public R execute(T request, Function<T, R> defaultHandler, Consumer<Exception> exceptionHandler) {
        return execute(request, Optional.of(defaultHandler), Optional.of(exceptionHandler));
    }

    public R execute(T request, Supplier<R> defaultSupplier) {
        final Function<T, R> defaultHandler = (input) -> defaultSupplier.get();
        return execute(request, Optional.of(defaultHandler), Optional.empty());
    }

    private R execute(T request, Optional<Function<T, R>> defaultHandler, Optional<Consumer<Exception>> exceptionHandler) {
        Optional<R> response;
        try {
            for (final Function<T,Optional<R>> handler: handlers) {
                response = handler.apply(request);

                if (response.isPresent()) {
                    return response.get();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            handleOrLog(exceptionHandler, exception);
        }

        return getDefaultResponse(defaultHandler, request);
    }

    private void handleOrLog(Optional<Consumer<Exception>> exceptionHandler, Exception exception) {
        if (exceptionHandler.isPresent()) {
            exceptionHandler.get().accept(exception);
            return;
        }
        LOGGER.error("Unhandled exception occurred while executing handler chain. This most probably is a developer error.");
    }

    private R getDefaultResponse(Optional<Function<T, R>> defaultHandler, T request) {
        if (defaultHandler.isPresent()) {
            return defaultHandler.get().apply(request);
        }
        return getDefaultResponse();
    }

    public R getDefaultResponse() {
        return defaultResponse;
    }

    public static class Builder<T, R> {
        private final ChainedExecutor<T, R> chainedExecutor = new ChainedExecutor<>();

        public Builder(List<Function<T,Optional<R>>> handlers) {
            Validate.notNull(handlers);
            for (final Function<T, Optional<R>> handler: handlers) {
                Validate.notNull(handler);
                handlers.add(handler);
            }
        }

        public Builder() {}

        public ChainedExecutor.Builder<T, R> withHandler(Function<T, Optional<R>> handler) {
            Validate.notNull(handler);
            chainedExecutor.handlers.add(handler);
            return this;
        }

        public ChainedExecutor.Builder<T, R> withDefaultResponse(R defaultResponse) {
            Validate.notNull(defaultResponse);
            chainedExecutor.defaultResponse = defaultResponse;
            return this;
        }

        public ChainedExecutor<T, R> build() {
            Validate.isTrue(!chainedExecutor.handlers.isEmpty());
            return chainedExecutor;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I ended up not doing this. It was just a thought which crossed my mind. I felt that it would make it more cryptic for my colleagues. Though, I really like removing if/else. I went OOPS way (Polymorphism).

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the first version looks much simpler and easier to read, thus I would go with that if there is no win in performance in the second version. Extraction of some generic method would be good, but it seems that it is not so straight forward because each `StateValidator` looks different.

Answer (score 0):

`findFirst` could be used to short circuit sequential stream of operations and hence implement [Chain-of-responsibility_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

```
public Response getResponse(RequestStateInfo requestStateInfo) {
        Response response = null;

        try {
            response = handlers.stream()
                    .sequential()
                    .map(handler->handler.apply(requestStateInfo))
                    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                    .map(Optional::get)
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(getDefaultResponse(requestStateInfo));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Some log", e);
            response = getDefaultResponse(requestStateInfo);
        }
        return response;
    }
```